# Why does this print() trigger twice each time?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My print function is running more than once in my code, here's the code and the running result below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
@State private var counter = 0

var body: some View {
   Text("Hello, World!")
       .onReceive(timer) { time in
            if self.counter == 5 {
            self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            }
            else {
                self.counter += 1
                print("The time is now \(time)")
            }
       }
   }
}
```

[running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQERw.jpg)

Comment: your view might be being instantiated more than once in that amount of time.

Comment: works fine here. tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2